# controller's action parameter doesn't accept /

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have controller's action

```
    public string Index(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
```

I have only this route in Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{id}", 
            new { controller = "Start", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }              
        );
```

For url like this "http://localhost/stuff" and "http://localhost/hello" it works. But it doesn't work for url like "http://localhost/stuff/add". How can I fix it?

Comment: How exactly do you want it to work?

Comment: /home/staff must display string "home/staff". But now "/hello" display "hello"(properly works) and /hello/test display error

Comment: An 'id' cannot contain a '/'. This is not a proper way to use routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add wildcard (asterisk) before the id:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{*id}",
            new {controller = "Start", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```